# RestTemplate exchange() returns partial data

Tags: java, spring-boot

My restTemplate call
`restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                String.class).getBody();`
returns partial data.

The JSON string returned is as follows: 
`{"data":[{"date":"2019-03-18T17:00:00.000Z"},{"date":"2019-03-18T18:00:00.000Z"}]}`

Whereas if I try the same call using Postman, I get the following JSON,
`{
    "data": [
        {
            "temperature": 21.9,
            "ambient_light_level": 353891.4,
            "date": "2019-03-18T17:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-03-18T18:00:00.000Z",
            "temperature": 22.9,
            "ambient_light_level": 353894.4
        }]}`

What am I missing here? Why is the JSON returned by exchange() truncated /different?

Comment: It's not truncated, that's the full content returned by the server, for whatever reason. We don't have enough to go on here.

Comment: show the mapping POJO for the above JSON

Comment: theres no POJO as of now. I m getting that value in String for time being and inspecting it via debugger